# Xamarin restryle the push notification when app is in killed state

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am receiving Firebase push notification and restyling it before display to the user. This will work on app in foreground and background also. When I killed the app notification is handling by the system itself. How do I handle it?

I follow the [tutorial](https://github.com/jfversluis/XFFCMPushNotificationsSample) which uses Plugin.FirebasePushNotification
In  android project Application.cs is handling the styling of the push notification

//Handle notification when app is closed here

```
    CrossFirebasePushNotification.Current.OnNotificationReceived += (s, p) =>
            {

             NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "CHANNELID1");
             builder.SetContentTitle("Good Morning");
             builder.SetContentText("Hi, Pls visit our shop");
             builder.SetSmallIcon(Application.Context.ApplicationInfo.Icon);
             builder.SetPriority(NotificationCompat.PriorityHigh);
             builder.SetAutoCancel(true); //disappear after sometime
             var notificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService);
             notificationManager.Notify(notification_id, builder.Build());

            };
```

**But How do I add the above code in App.xaml.cs to handle the receive message while app is in Killed state**

**App.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class App : Application
    {
        public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            MainPage = new MainPage();
            CrossFirebasePushNotification.Current.OnTokenRefresh += Current_OnTokenRefresh;

            
            CrossFirebasePushNotification.Current.OnNotificationReceived += (s, p) =>
            {

             NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "CHANNELID1");
             builder.SetContentTitle("Good Morning");
             builder.SetContentText("Hi, Pls visit our shop");
             builder.SetSmallIcon(Application.Context.ApplicationInfo.Icon);
             builder.SetPriority(NotificationCompat.PriorityHigh);
             builder.SetAutoCancel(true); //disappear after sometime
             var notificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService);
             notificationManager.Notify(notification_id, builder.Build());

            };
        }
    }
```

The issue is **NotificationCompat** and other classes are specific to the android

Need your advise on the above